# How to attach onclick event for a JavaScript generated textbox?

Tags: javascript, textbox, calendar, onclick

I have a table row which contains a textbox and it has an onclick which displays a JavaScript calendar... I am adding rows to the table with textbox, but I don't know how to attach onclick event to the JavaScript generated textbox...

```
<input  class="date_size_enquiry" type="text" autocomplete="off"
onclick="displayDatePicker('attendanceDateadd1');" size="21" readonly="readonly"    
maxlength="11" size="11"  name="attendanceDateadd1" id="attendanceDateadd1" 
value="" onblur="per_date()" onchange="fnloadHoliday(this.value);">
```

And my JavaScript generates a textbox,

```
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.setAttribute('align','center')
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.className = "date_size_enquiry";
    el.type = 'text';
    el.name = 'attendanceDateadd' + iteration;
    el.id = 'attendanceDateadd' + iteration;
    el.onClick = //How to call the function displayDatePicker('attendanceDateadd1');
    e1.onblur=??
    e1.onchange=??
    cell2.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: I believe attaching events dinamically is not cross browser, so you may need to write different code for different browsers. I suggest using a JS libray like JQuery for that purpose. With JQuery it's as simple as this: `$('#elementId').click(function() { /* Do what you want here */});`

Comment: @eyazici: The DOM manipulation strategy the OP is using is safe with the exception of `setAttribute()`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like this:

```
var el = document.createElement('input');
...
el.onclick = function() {
    displayDatePicker('attendanceDateadd1');
};
```

BTW: Be careful with case sensitivity in the DOM. It's `"onclick"`, not `"onClick"`.

Comment: @ Asaph it didnt work `el.onClick = function(){alert(el.id);};`

Comment: @chandru_cp: Don't capitalize the "c" in "onclick". It's a lower case "c". See the last line of my answer.

Comment: sorry one of my friend used my system

Answer (score 4):

Taking your example, I think you want to do this:

```
el.onclick = function() { displayDatePicker(el.id); };
```

The only trick is to realise why you need to wrap your `displayDatePicker` call in the `function() { ... }` code. Basically, you need to assign a function to the `onclick` property, however in order to do this you can't just do `el.onclick = displayDatePicker(el.id)` since this would tell javascript to execute the `displayDatePicker` function and assign the result to the `onclick` handler rather than assigning the function call itself. So to get around this you create an anonymous function that in turn calls your `displayDatePicker`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
el.onclick = function(){
  displayDatePicker(this.id);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML5/ES6 approach:

```
var el = document.createElement('input')

[...]

el.addEventListener('click', function () {
  displayDatePicker('attendanceDateadd1')
})
```