# How do I prevent a JavasScript function from launching when the browser loads?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

So I created a function (onSuccess) that launches when an AJAX request is successful. The problem is that my function launches when my browser loads and I would only like for the function only to be called when a button with id myButton is clicked. I am locating my button using `document.getElementById("myButton");` but when I run `console.log(document.getElementById("myButton"));` in my browser console I get a Null result.

I've looked around and gotten a few suggestions stating that my element wasn't in the DOM when my script ran. I can understand that but when I moved the location of my script and moved the `document.getElementById...` my script still doesn't work. I viewed a few suggestions on Stackoverflow but they were mostly JQuery solutions. I'm looking for a pure JavaScript solution. My  code is below

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jimmyt1001/yw26ncba/8/)

```
            var el = document.getElementById("myButton");
            el.onclick = addUser("username", "email", onSuccess);

            function onSuccess(result){
               alert ('successful');
            }



            // Do not modify this function. Add user service wrapper.
            function addUser(username, email, callback) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var response;
                var success = (!!Math.round(Math.random()));

                if (!success){
                    response = JSON.stringify({
                        success: success,
                        error: "Oups, something went wrong!"
                    });
                } else {
                    response = JSON.stringify({
                        success: success,
                        user: {
                            username: username,
                            email: email
                        }
                    });   
                }

                xhr.open("POST", "/echo/json/");
                xhr.onload = function () {
                        if (xhr.status === 200) {
                            callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                    }
                }
                xhr.send("json=" + response);
            };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've gone a little wrong here, but I think I know what you need to do.

You *want* to pass a function reference to the `onclick` attribute, but instead you're executing the function and setting `onclick` to be whatever that function returns.

This is why your function is running when the browser loads. You need to pass the reference; not execute it and pass the output of the function.

**So how do you solve it?**

There is a cool practice in functional programming called [Currying Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying). It's very useful in situations like this, when you need to pass in some parameters but you want to delay execution. In this case, you could do something like this:

```
function buildAddUser(username, email, callback) { 
    return function() {
        addUser(username, email, callback)
    }
}
```

Then, you set your button to be equal to the output of `buildAddUser`..

```
el.onclick = buildAddUser("username", "email", onSuccess);
```

This will set the `onclick` attribute to be equal to a function that invokes the `addUser` function.

**Why not just use an anonymous function?**

I prefer to wrap these things in named functions, to make your code easier to read. Anonymous functions flying all over the place can make things confusing.

**Extra Reading**

Functional Programming in Javascript is one of the most exciting new developments and offers a wide array of tools to help solve problems just like this. You should have a read through [some of the material available](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/why-learn-functional-programming-in-javascript-composing-software-ea13afc7a257)

Comment: This is great input! Will definitly read up on it. I figure that I should replace `el.onclick = buildAddUser("username", "email", onSuccess);` with `el.onclick = buildAddUser("username", "email", callback);` since you are using that parameter in your example. For some reason it's not working for me. I'm getting a " callback is not defined" error in my Fiddle example

Comment: You can use 'onSuccess' ! The name of the arguments isn't important; the crucial part here is the idea of using one function to hold the parameters and defer execution to a point that you want.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that is going wrong is that you are calling addUser when you try to set the onClick listener. Try this instead.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("myButton");
el.onclick = function() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value
  addUser(username, email, onSuccess)
}

function onSuccess(result){
   alert ('successful');
}



// Do not modify this function. Add user service wrapper.
function addUser(username, email, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var response;
    var success = (!!Math.round(Math.random()));
    
    if (!success){
        response = JSON.stringify({
            success: success,
            error: "Oups, something went wrong!"
        });
    } else {
        response = JSON.stringify({
            success: success,
            user: {
                username: username,
                email: email
            }
        });   
    }
    
    xhr.open("POST", "/echo/json/");
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
          callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        }
    }
    xhr.send("json=" + response);
};
```

```html
<h2>Add a User:</h2>
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="name">
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
<button id="myButton">add user</button>
<h2>Users:</h2>
<ul id="users"></ul>
```

Comment: This is another good way around the problem! Nice thinking. +1

Comment: @Jimmy can you tell me what error you are getting? notice I also added id in the Html so I can get the values.

Comment: @Jimmy The snippet doesn't respond as intended on SO, I edited your jsFiddle so now it should work  [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Frithjof/jetmh6me/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Create anonymous function call which wraps the function

`el.onclick = function() { addUser("username", "email", onSuccess); };`

For more detailed explanation you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226953/how-to-attach-onclick-event-for-a-javascript-generated-textbox?rq=1)